# Get Status Code on CORS Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

How do you `return` a response code from a CORS Request? I am able to get it from an onload event, but I cannot seem to take it out and make a `return` so that I can catch it for value checking.

Here is my code based on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/:

```
createCORSRequest: function(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

      // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
      // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
      xhr.open(method, url, true);

    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

      // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
      // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
      xhr = new XDomainRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);

    } else {

      // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
      xhr = null;

    }
    return xhr;
  },

  makeCorsRequest: function() {
    // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
    var me = this;
    var url = 'http://google.com';
    var sCode = '';

    var xhr = me.createCORSRequest('GET', url);
    console.log('xhr', xhr);
    if (!xhr) {
      alert('CORS not supported');
      return;
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var text = xhr.responseText;
      var sCode = xhr.status;
      // var title = getTitle(text);
      // alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + xhr.status);
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(this.status);
      sCode = this.status;
    }

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
    };

    xhr.send();
    return sCode; // this returns an empty string or the initial value set to it and not from `onload` event
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you are returning the 'status' before the response is returned. You might need to take into account that the `onerror`, `onload` etc events will be fired asynchronously and only then you will have `status` code available. Callbacks or Promise could be helpful.

Comment: Can you share how you are making call to `makeCorsRequest` ?

Comment: Hi @AnkitMishra. I'm using AngularJS so I'm calling it from my factory like so: `statusCode = $payments.makeCorsRequest();`

Comment: Oh I see, you would need to make makeCorsRequest either a [Promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) or use a [callback](https://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/). Because your current code is expecting response Synchronously but above XHR requests is Asynchronus, hence `sCode` is returned without ever being assigned.

Comment: @AnkitMishra: Not sure how that would be written in Angular. I'm assuming it is implemented in a way I write success/error callbacks for $http?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be the use of Callback in JS, as we can pass Functions in JavaScript as parameters to other functions, and invoke them asynchronously from inside.

I have modified your code a little to make it respond asynchronously, and added relevant comments. Observe the use of `callback` below.

```
//make few changes to make it asynchronous.
makeCorsRequest: function(callback) {
    // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
    var me = this;
    var url = 'http://google.com';
    var sCode = '';

    var xhr = me.createCORSRequest('GET', url);
    console.log('xhr', xhr);
    if (!xhr) {
      callback('CORS not supported');
      return;
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var text = xhr.responseText;
      var sCode = xhr.status;
      // var title = getTitle(text);
      // alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + xhr.status);
      callback(null, text);
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(this.status);
      callback(this.status);
    }

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      callback('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
    };

    xhr.send();
  }

//this function would be the callback, it would be called 'Asynchronously' form XHR events with err or real data. First parameter generally indicates error.
function handleCorsResponse(err, data) {
   //check if error occurred
   if (err) {
      //error handling here
   }

  //if no error occurred, proceed.
   console.log(data);
}

//let's call `makeCorsRequest` with `handleCorsResponse` as a parameter.
$payments.makeCorsRequest(handleCorsResponse);
```

**Note** : A better and recommended way would be using a [Promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).